# How to change screen orientation (programmatically) to "Reverse Landscape" using appium (selenium driver)

Tags: android, selenium, rotation

I am using `Appium` to automate mobile app, and I need to change screen orientation.

This works for me:

```
((Rotatable)driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
((Rotatable)driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT);
```

But, when I use:

```
((Rotatable)driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

My screen rotates only to the right, but I need the rotation to theleft `Reverse Landscape`.

Comment: Did you try to put loop with rotate?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times you call: ((Rotatable)driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);

Screen stays on the right Landscape